# Liberar IPA sin la cuenta de Developer iOS

Tags: xcode

Actualmente me encuentro en el dilema de tener que liberar una version de IPA de mi proyecto iOS , en donde no "puedo" tener la cuenta de developer del cliente.

tomando esto en cuenta es posible generar el archivo ipa ( Yo tengo el proyecto en mi xcode y soy el duenño del codigo , pero el cliente lo quiere liberar el en su cuenta de developer, esto es posible,  de ser asi como se lograria?

Comment: Podrías solicitarle a tu cliente que genere(si no lo tienen), exporte y comparta el certificado Ad-Hoc y su respectivo Provisioning Profile. Con eso, deberías ser capaz de generarles el ipa.

Comment: @VladimirEspinolaLezcano como serian los pasos a seguir